# Will Azure DevOps Team admins have the access to create permission group for the team and add/delete members from it?

Tags: azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps for development. Is it possible for Team administrator have the access to create permission groups for the team and add/delete members from it? Here, Team Administrator is not member of Project Administrator permission group?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot create groups as team admin. However, you can add existing groups to the team

Comment: @Cid Can you please explain on how groups can be added to a Team? Can the groups be classified under a team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Administrator has no right to add or delete the permission groups and only the Project Administrator from the Organization Settings has the right to do that. So you have to use Project Administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @perry. 

When we are adding a new team to use the Project for development, based on our understanding, the team has to contact the Project Administrator every time, to add/delete members to/from the security groups. Are there any approaches available, that we can follow to handle this?